# Jar running on Amazon EC2 t2.micro instance runs out of memory

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, memory-management, amazon-ec2, jvm

I am running some web app on an Amazon instance from a Java jar, but it always runs out of memory after 12 hours or so.  Here is the error message that gets written to a file:

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 12288 bytes for                              
committing reserved memory.
Possible reasons:
 The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
 In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
Possible solutions:
 Reduce memory load on the system
 Increase physical memory or swap space
 Check if swap backi ng store is full
 Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
 Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
 Decrease number of Java threads
 Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
 Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
 This output file may be truncated or incomplete.

Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2827), pid=5808, tid=140367928600320

JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_95) (build 1.7.0_95-b00)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.95-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.4
Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, package 7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. 
To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

How do I proceed from here?  Would following their suggestions such as increasing the heap size or swap space make sense, or do I really just need to upgrade my EC2 instance to a larger size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you ran out of either virtual memory or actual address space.

This means you should either

- increase the swap space
- **decrease** the heap size

The reason you need to decrease the heap size is to leave more memory for the rest of the JVM and system

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the maximum JVM heap size setting via the `-Xmx` option to allow the JVM to use more memory. If you need to increase it beyond what is physically available on a t2.micro instance, then you also need to increase your EC2 instance size.

Keep in mind that you won't be able to allocate the full 1GB of memory on the t2.micro instance to your Java application because some of that will be in use by the operating system. Also you need to avoid using swap space if at all possible, so concentrate on configuring your JVM to make use of the RAM available on the EC2 instance.

Without knowing what your current JVM settings are it's difficult to give more exact recommendations.

Comment: Hmm.. but the error message is recommending decreasing the heap size.

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe you've allocated more memory than actually exists on the server. In any case, you need to provide your current JVM settings if you want a more exact recommendation.

Comment: How can I get the current JVM settings?  Do I need to write a Java program or can I do it from the command line?

Comment: Why would you think you need to "write a java program" to get the settings you are using to run your current program? You just need to provide the settings that are being used on the command line when you run your Java program. If the program is currently running you might be able to find that via `ps -ef | grep java`.

Comment: I am just running the program via java -jar <jarname>.

Comment: Then you are using the defaults. You can see the default max heap size by running `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version 2>&1 | grep MaxHeapSize`. At the very least you need to set that setting manually since the default is allowing Java to attempt to use more RAM than is physically available. I suspect your program needs more ram than a t2.micro can provide however, since this issue is happening, so you probably also need to upgrade your instance to something with more RAM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104910/discussion-between-bob-bobson-the-third-esq-and-mark-b).

Comment: Note it suggest you "Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)" not increase it. I suggest you update your answer to reflect this.